# Want to send header with screen scraping

Tags: php, curl, screen-scraping, file-get-contents

i am still stucked in screen scraping problem...
link : [screen scraping in php problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513083/screen-scraping-in-php-problem)

This problem was solved to little extent by using `'&num=100'` in google search query which decreased the no. of request 10 times.But captcha problem is still dere. So to overcome it i used...`sleep(seconds)` function.

Now the problem is I have to scrape it myself(these are orders).that means i dont want to use '`simple_html_dom.php`' becuase catching warnings and error is difficult(for me) in this case.i m instructed to do it myself. so how i can i do it.i know to methods: 1. file_get_content() 2. curl.

But its very tedious work to fetch search for ur content and count rank simultaneously.as using regular exp to parse dom is HELL.read this link for convencing urself.link: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Task to implemented :

1. catch captcha error(or warning) so i can stop furhter execution.
2. Have to use headers.so it seems to be genuine and valid humanable request to google.

   simple_html_dom.php cant catch errors.it shows warning when captcha error occurs.How can i catch that warning?
   Please help...its long working with this module.Please give suggestion to solve each and every problem related here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know about the first problem (captcha), but you can send headers easily with curl, for example:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept-Charset: utf-8'));
```

And to set the user agent:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:2.2a1pre) Gecko/20110324 Firefox/4.2a1pre');
```

Comment: thanks..i was looking for similar stuff...can u send me php.net link listing ol possilble 'CURLOPT_<sumthing>' options??

Comment: http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php. List of all  curlopt_ options..